# get the full_name of a repository through the github API

Tags: git, github, github-api, github-api-v3

I want to get some information about github repositories using only their name. To do so, I build my url as `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/<TheName>` But of course it doesn't work because I need the :owner field. I found many ways to get different information on the github api documentation page but none to get the owner. Is there any way to easily get it?

e.g. for input "spring-boot" repo , api should return full_name i.e. spring-projects/spring-boot 
(as git url for spring-boot is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for a simple reason! different users can have identical names for their repositories!
for example, user_1 can have a repository named: `foo` (`user_1/foo`) and user_2 can have another repository named `foo` too! (`user_2/foo`). so there is no guarantee that you have unique repositories for a given name.

If you want to get a list of all of the public repositories named `foo` from Github, I think currently there is no API for handling that.

Comment: Then I think not possible to get the source URL of a repository through the github API (using only repo name)?